# Unity крашится при открытии документа Word

Tags: c#, unity3d

Столкнулся с проблемой. При программном открытии документа Word с шаблоном Unity крашится. Причём сама программа Word запускается, а при открытии документа крашится и Sysrem.Exception не успевает словить  ошибку. Документ открываю так:

```
Word.Document doc = null;
Word.Application app = new Word.Application();
object missingObj = Missing.Value;
object source = @“D:\Test.docx”;
doc = app.Documents.Open(ref sourse, ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj и т.д.)
```

И на последней этой строчке краш.

Comment: довольно спорное решение использовать интероп в юнити... а что если версия ворда не подходящая? А что если ворд на компьютере не стоит?

Comment: @Andrew, Это специфический проект. Так что всё стоять  будет. Нужно формализованный отчёт вывести.

Comment: а почему апликуха в игровом движке? Почему не в WPF или Winforms? Хотя даже в них возник бы вопрос стоит ли интероп использовать...

Comment: @Andrew , наглядное динамическое моделирование

Comment: А еще стоит в вопрос добавить стектрейс креша и текст/код ошибки.

Comment: @Andrew , ПК без доступа к интернету

Comment: ну перепиши текст вручную. Вряд ли найдется здесь оракул который догадается без текста ошибки как ее исправить.

Comment: @Andrew , проблема от куда его вытащить. Крашится не приложение, а плеер.

Comment: System Events...

Comment: @Andrew , немного не понял как им пользоваться... Не поймите не правильно. Просто это первый проект на Unity и дебажил только через консоль...

Comment: @Andrew , mono-2.0-bdwgc.dll caused an Access Violation (0xc0000005)

Comment: Вообще, судя по ошибкам, вы натыкаетесь не столько на проблемы с подержкой в Mono COM Interop, сколько на что-то банальное, типа отсутствие необходимых библиотек. Word Interop зависит как минимум от Interop.Microsoft.Office.Core.dll и Interop.VBIDE.dll (они генерируются автоматически при добавлении ссылки на Word Object Library в студии). Если моно не поддерживает встраивание interop-сборок, они должны лежать в папке с программой.

Comment: @ MSDN.WhiteKnight, 
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll, Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.dll, office.dll, stdole.dll - Эти? Лежат.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте через `ProcessStartInfo`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;
using UnityEngine;

public class exec : MonoBehaviour {

     public void ExecuteCommand () {
         new Thread(delegate () {Command(cmd);}).Start();
     }
 
     void Command (){
         var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("ping.exe", "yandex.ru");
         //processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
         //processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 
         var process = Process.Start(processInfo);
         
         process.WaitForExit();
         process.Close();
     }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну, проверил. Запускается.

Comment: @IncDD winword? у меня он просто не установлен..

Comment: дело в том, что Word запускается без проблем. А вот документ Test.docx с шаблоном - нет. И крашится именно в том моменте, где пытается открыть документ.

Comment: @IncDD даже через exec?

Comment: @IncDD расшарьте файлик с шаблоном, или он пустой? какая винда, какой офис?

Comment: файлик куда только не закидывал. Win 7 sp1 x64, office 2007

Comment: @IncDD нет вы не поняли, расшарьте нам, для скачивания

Comment: я писал выше - ПК без доступа к сети. Я на мобилке палец разминаю :)

Comment: @IncDD вы используете контроль версий? папку Library удаляли?

Comment: нет, папку не удалял

Comment: @IncDD а через exec так же крашится? а если сделать START winword.exe "не_знаю_как_там_передавать_ворду_аргумент_до_фалйа.docx"

Comment: ага, через exec открывает. Но дело то в том, что мне в закладки документа данные вписывать надо из скрипта...

Comment: Вытащил ошибку - COMException System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR (Int32 errorCode) (бла бла бла /Marshal.cs:1031)

Comment: @IncDD а если в trycatch завернуть то не помогает?)

Comment: Первое что сделал. Крашится прям в try не выводя ошибку в catch :)